# SpringBoot: Imp SpringSecurity : while login with user/pass getting Screen error msg "User is disabled"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I just start implementing SpringSecurity but post login getting Error Message on Screen "User is disabled"

IT'S WORKING VERY WELL FOR DEFAULT .
WHILE HITTING WITH /user or /admin and trying to login it's showing **"User is disable"**

I am following below step:

1. First created schema.sql (under resource folder)

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE USERS (
       USERNAME VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
       PASSWORD VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
       ENABLED CHAR(1) CHECK (ENABLED IN ('Y','N') ) NOT NULL
   );

   CREATE TABLE AUTHORITIES (
       USERNAME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
       AUTHORITY VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
   );

   ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES ADD CONSTRAINT AUTHORITIES_UNIQUE UNIQUE (USERNAME, AUTHORITY);
   ALTER TABLE AUTHORITIES ADD CONSTRAINT AUTHORITIES_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME) REFERENCES USERS (USERNAME);
   ```
2. Created "data.sql" under resource folder

   ```sql
   insert into USERS(USERNAME,PASSWORD,ENABLED) VALUES ('user','pass','Y');
   insert into USERS(USERNAME,PASSWORD,ENABLED) VALUES ('admin','pass','Y');
   insert into AUTHORITIES (USERNAME,AUTHORITY) values ('user','ROLE_USER');
   insert into AUTHORITIES (USERNAME,AUTHORITY) values ('admin','ROLE_ADMIN');
   ```
3. HomeResource.JAVA ( This is a controller class API)

   ```java
   package com.example.callCenter;

   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

   @RestController
   public class HomeResource{

       @GetMapping("/")
       public String home(){
           return("<h1>Welcome home page..</h1>");
       }

       @GetMapping("/user")
       public String user()
       {
           return ("<h1>Welcome User page</h1>");
       }

       @GetMapping("/admin")
       public String admin()
       {
           return("<h1>Welcome Admin page</h1>");
       }
   }
   ```
4. SecurityConfiguration.java ( This is enable the Spring Form PAGE)

   ```java
   package com.example.callCenter;

   import javax.sql.DataSource;

   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
   import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
   import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
   import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

       @Autowired
       DataSource dataSource;

       @Override
       protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
           auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
               .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled "
                           + "from users "
                           + "where username = ?")
               .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username,AUTHORITY  "
                           + "from AUTHORITIES "
                           + "where username = ?");

           // This beloe code is default implementation with MySQL database
           // auth.jdbcAuthentication()
           //         .dataSource(dataSource)
           //         .withDefaultSchema()
           //         .withUser( 
           //                     User.withUsername("user")
           //                     .password("pass")
           //                     .roles("USER")

           //         )
           //         .withUser( 
           //                     User.withUsername("admin")
           //                     .password("pass")
           //                     .roles("ADMIN")
           //         );

       }

       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.csrf().disable()
               .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                   .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                   .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                   .and().formLogin();
       }

       @Bean
       public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder()
       {
           return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
       }

   }
   ```
5. CallApplication.java

   ```java
   package com.example.callCenter;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class CallApplication {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(CallCenterApplication.class, args);
       }

   }
   ```

   **pom.xml :** given all the dependency that is not a issue because form is opening

   **application.properties :**

   ```
   spring.datasource.url=
   spring.datasource.username=
   spring.datasource.password=
   spring.datasource.driverClassName=

   spring.jpa.show_sql=true
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
   spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
   spring.jpa.format_sql=true
   ```

I added almost all the details there are nothing pending from my side but now I want some one assistance why it's not allow me to call the user and allow me to login.

Comment: CREATE TABLE USERS (
    USERNAME VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    --ENABLED CHAR(1) CHECK (ENABLED IN ('Y','N') ) NOT NULL
 ENABLED BIT DEFAULT 1
 --BitColumn       BIT DEFAULT 1
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is with the value stored in column

`ENABLED CHAR(1) CHECK (ENABLED IN ('Y','N') ) NOT NULL`

JdbcUserDetailsManager.[loadUsersByUsername(String username)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/171e0d048f46528bd02312c6c18da4586cc7c974/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.java#L149) has the following code logic to populate its properties when creating User object.

```
                String userName = rs.getString(1);
                String password = rs.getString(2);
                boolean enabled = rs.getBoolean(3);
```

To get the `enabled` status ,  [ResultSet.getBoolean()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is used and the java docs for the same mentions the following

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of
>   this ResultSet object as a boolean in the Java programming language.
>
> If the designated column has a datatype of CHAR or VARCHAR and
>   contains a "0" or has a datatype of BIT, TINYINT, SMALLINT, INTEGER or
>   BIGINT and contains a 0, a value of false is returned. If the
>   designated column has a datatype of CHAR or VARCHAR and contains a "1"
>   or has a datatype of BIT, TINYINT, SMALLINT, INTEGER or BIGINT and
>   contains a 1, a value of true is returned.

In the above code , the correct values for enabled/disabled are '1' and '0' respectively.